# Overflow function in html input box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a form where the user can update data

```
<dl>
    <dt>Medical Needs:</dt>
    <dd class="med_needs" style="height:60px;overflow:auto">
        <input type = "text" id="med_needs"name ="med_needs" value ="<?php echo $row2['med_needs'];  ?>" style=" width:90%; height:50px;"/>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

The input box I have for the user right now is not a scroll box. So what happens is the existing data cannot be seen in a user friendly way. If it were a scroll box, it would be easier to read and update. I tried using overflow:auto as a style in the input tag but it did not change the appearance at all.

What I want is for the user to have a scrollable box to edit from, where they can read existing contents before editing

Comment: Look at your HTML markup: after the style argument there is a useless "

Comment: Question does not contain a question.

Comment: typo corrected. It was an error during copy paste and does not change what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would `overflow-y: scroll;` help?

Comment: I just tried that after reading your comment but it did not make the box scrollable.

Comment: Could you use a textarea?

Comment: When I try that the text is not visible to the user even though I echo it out using php

Comment: Remember that a textarea has a closing tag and no value attribute.

Comment: Thanks @Wipster you are a genius! I was struggling with this for a while. Totally accept your answer !!!